# How to fix "The following languages have no built-in quality profiles" since SQ 7.2.1 with custom plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-plugin

I develop custom SQ plugins for several SQ versions. I am facing a issue since SQ 7.2.1.
On SQ startup, le web.log file tells

```
-normal Register rules
-start [o.s.s.q.BuiltInQProfileRepositoryImpl] Load quality profiles
-stops with the following error : [o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
-java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following languages have no built-in quality profiles: csh
```

Note csh is my language name

The SQ startup is fine for version 7.1 and previous with my plugin

How to configure the custom plugin to solve this issue ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the `BuiltInQualityProfilesDefinition` extension point to list rules that should be enabled by default for your language.

Prior to SonarQube 7.2 it was not mandatory to declare a built in quality profile for each language, but it was causing some bugs. See https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10283

Comment: Thanks Julien. This extension point seams to be optional from SQ 6.6 and < 7.2.1, and compulsory from SQ 7.2.1 and above.